# select from table1 depend on newest date in table 2

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables like above 
table1 = items => id, name
table 2 = item_price => item_id, date,price
I need to

```
select items.name from items 
INNER JOIN item_price ON items.id = item_price2.item_id
where item_price.date is last date
```

```
items
id      name
1       item name 1
2       item name 2
3       item name 3
```

```
    item_price
    item_id  date            price
    1        2022-01-13      5
    2        2022-01-10      7
    1        2022-01-10      4
    1        2022-01-09      9
```

I need build query to get this result

```
 item name             price
 item name 1            5
 item name 2            7
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by selecting the last row using the ROW_NUMBER windowed partition function.

```
WITH last_item_price (item_id, price, reverse_order)
AS
  (SELECT item_id
   , price
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
     (PARTITION BY item_id 
     ORDER BY date DESC) AS reverse_order
  FROM item_price)
SELECT i.name
  , p.price
FROM items i
JOIN last_item_price p
  ON i.item_id = p.item_id
  AND p.reverse_order = 1;
```

Unless the primary key of item_price is defined as the composite key for item_id and date, there is a risk you will have more than one possible price.  For instance, if the price changes three times on a single day, then how do you know which is the correct value?  I would recommend using a DATETIME or DATETIME2 field to help pick the correct price in that scenario.  Alternatively, you can define the primary key as the composite of the two fields and only allow a single price each day.

Another way to avoid the duplication issue is to add an auto-incrementing identity column.  This will not be useful for joins and I still strongly recommend using a composite key for the item_id and date fields, but it is a valid alternative.  In that case, you can modify the partition function's ORDER BY clause to:

```
ORDER BY date DESC, item_price_id DESC
```

In general, I would not recommend naming a field date.  Since SQL Server has a data type called DATE, this can cause issues with linters.  In some cases, you may be required to use brackets so the field is [date] to disambiguate your intent.  A better name is probably price_date or price_change_date.